# term for reading non-fiction for enjoyment even though you don't believe it

Tags: word-choice, phrase-usage, idiom-request

Is there a term that means, "reading non-fiction for enjoyment even though you don't believe it"?

For instance, reading conspiracy theory/UFO books for enjoyment even though you don't believe in these things.

Comment: Hello user1265564! Welcome to this site! Please use proper grammar and capitalization.

Answer (score 1):

**Guilty pleasure** is used to refer to some form of activity or entertainment that you enjoy even though you (think) you shouldn't.

> I have a friend who is a gourmet chef and cookbook author.  Her *guilty pleasure* is the butter frosting on supermarket cupcakes - she can't get enough of it.
>
> Everyone knows Shakespeare was a historically great playwright.  Fewer know of his *guilty pleasure* - scrawling bawdy limericks on privvy walls.  [NOTE: I made that up - Adam]

Here's one I didn't make up.  Gene Siskel, reknowned film critic, discussing low-brow cinema:

> SISKEL: My final **guilty pleasure,** a film I'm, embarassed almost to admit I like, is a film that starts out like a mad slasher movie, except it turns out to be a rubber knife,...and I don't think I've knocked any other category of film more often than slasher pictures...[Funhouse](http://tobehooperfunhouse.blogspot.com/2011/06/siskel-and-ebert-on-funhouse.html)

With his partner, Rober Ebert, Siskel did a whole episode of *guilty-pleasure* reviews - movies that they were a little ashamed to enjoy as much as they did.

Answer (score 0):

**Suspension of disbelief** is a phrase we use when reading something that requires us to accept, at least temporarily, the beliefs espoused by an author when we do not agree with them. We are thus "suspending" or "putting on hold" our *disbelief* in what the author says.

[Suspension of disbelief](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/suspension+of+disbelief)

> a willingness to suspend one's critical faculties and believe the unbelievable; sacrifice of realism and logic **for the sake of enjoyment**

*However*, I myself am more familiar with the seemingly opposite phrase, **suspension of *belief***. To me, this also makes sense for the exact same situation. Here we are "suspending" or "putting on hold" our own belief(s) in order to accept, at least temporarily, the beliefs or arguments of the author. Here is one [example](http://www.armedwithpens.com/an-introduction-to-screenwriting-suspension-of-belief/) usage. [Here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/263200/discussions/1/624075566734150407/) is another, concise, example:

> **Suspension of belief issue**
>
> So...
>   We can put a giant metal wall-locker into a small wooden chest and then place that in an even smaller satchel and place this into another bigger metal box then put it in a small meatbag and finally fit that into the inventory backpack?
>
> This doesn't make any sense!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't believe it is factual, you are treating it as fiction. You could say you read it "as a story", or "like fiction".  Or if you think it is humorous in its non-believability, you could say you read it "for amusement".

Any of these phrasings would let the hearer know that you read that kind of stuff, but you don't believe it.